# AS3: simulate a click to DisplayObject with coordinates and affect a child

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

So I need to simulate a click on a specific position on some DisplayObject. That's easy:

```
myObject.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, true, true, 200, 200));
```

The problem I'm having is that I need to dispatch a MouseEvent on some button IF it's at the position of the click in the container. But that won't happen so far...

My logic is that if I dispatch the event directly on the container, the event can't be dispatched on some child. But I'm not sure that is correct.

So how can I do that?
How can I dispatch an even to a DisplayObject and affect its children if there are indeed children at

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.

I need to use getObjectsUnderPoint() first to know what objects are under the coordinates, then figure out which is the top object, and then generate the MouseEvent on that object.